# Plotting an 'average' graph of 5 graphs

Tags: python, plot, gnuplot

Suppose,
I have some data points which define 5 different graphs like in the picture below.

**How can I draw an average graph of these over the values of the y-axis**?
I can not do it directly because the data points of different graphs have not the same values over the x-axis.

Comment: What exactly is average graph for you mathematically?

Comment: Is the data all in one file or multiple files?

Comment: @VladimirF for a given value x (e.g. 5), the average value will be approximately  $\bar{y} = (4.9 + 10.6 + 16.7 + 20 + 25) / 5 $, that is, the average value over the y axis for the 5 graphs. then I will have a data-point at (x, $\bar{y}$)

Comment: @mgilson , in multiple files, but this is not a problem, I can put them in a single file, there no a lit of data-points ...

Comment: I have to question the value of this average. First, you're averaging a different number of values when you look at the full X axis.  (Averaging 5 values where X = 0; only 1 value (?) where X = 40.) Second, the "average" where X > 20 seems *less* than all the values you seem to want to average. That's an odd behavior for a value that's supposed to represent central tendency.

Comment: @Catcall suppose that the y value is stable after the end of each graph that I draw. For instance, the blue red, after x = 20 we suppose that all values are are equals to the value of y where x = 20 (i.e. to 3)

Comment: @shn Do you know how to plot one of the graphs in pyplot?

Comment: I've ;learned not to suppose things that aren't on the graph. But I come out of a quality control background.  In any case, if I assume a flat line where every plot line stops, your average should still be substantially higher than your red line. I'm not saying what you have is wrong; I'm just saying I had to question it. Because it's, well, queestionable. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def line_tuple(filename,cols=(0,1)):
    return np.loadtxt(filename,usecols=cols,unpack=True)

#parse each line from the datafile into a tuple of the form (xvals,yvals)
#store that tuple in a list.
data = [line_tuple(fname) for fname in ("line1.txt","line2.txt","line3.txt","line4.txt","line5.txt")]

#This is the minimum and maximum from all the datapoints.
xmin = min(line[0].min() for line in data)
xmax = max(line[0].max() for line in data)

#100 points evenly spaced along the x axis
x_points = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,100)

#interpolate your values to the evenly spaced points.
interpolated = [np.interp(x_points,d[0],d[1]) for d in data]

#Now do the averaging.
averages = [np.average(x) for x in zip(*interpolated)]

#put the average value along with it's x point into a file.
with open('outfile','w') as fout:
    for x,avg in zip(x_points,averages):
        fout.write('{0} {1}\n'.format(x,avg))
```

and now I plot it:

```
plot 'line1.txt' w l, \
     'line2.txt' w l, \
     'line3.txt' w l, \
     'line4.txt' w l, \
     'line5.txt' w l, \
     'outfile' w l
```

Comment: data contains al the data-points of the 5 files ? Randomly sorted ?

Comment: I'm just asking if I should put all the data-points in the variable data

Comment: @shn -- Yes, they all end up in the data list.  See my edit on how you might be able to construct it.

Comment: Anyway I'm getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\plot\averaging.py", line 10, in <module>

    interpolated = [np.interp(x_points,d[0],d[1]) for d in data]
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1053, in
 interp
    return compiled_interp(x, xp, fp, left, right)
ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array

Comment: @shn -- Unfortunately, I'm not sure how much I can help without having the data files to actually play with ... It looks like each line is only 10 points or so, you *might* be able to post the datafiles in your original post.

Comment: Well I have edited my post to add the data, and the new image

Comment: @shn -- I've edited my answer with what I think is a working solution.

Comment: @mgilson Fantastic answer, short and clear, +1. One question: is there a way to obtain errorbars for the interpolated estimate? (e.g. due to varying number of data points to average over.) Thanks